# Div se superpone usando propiedad top

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Pues estoy desarrollando una página web, y tengo algo parecido a esto:

HTML

```
<section>
 <article class="first">
  <!-- Resto de estructura -->
 </article>

 <article class="second">
  <!-- Resto de estructura -->
 </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.first{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color:blue;
 position: relative;
 top: 100px;
}

.second{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 background-color:red;
}
```

El problema está en que el article first se superpone por encima y no siguen el flujo correcto. Yo pensaba que esto pasaba cuando se usaba la position: absolute...

Comment: si quitas la propiedad `position:relative` de la clase `first` se deja de superponer, no se si es lo que quieres

Comment: Pero la idea es poder posicionar el div o article (o el elemento que sea) segun quiera, si quito la position relative no podré posicionarlo...

Comment: pero cómo quieres que quede exactamente? cuál es la duda?

Comment: Debes aclarar mejor que es lo que pretendes, ten en cuenta que tal y como lo estás diciendo ahora te contradices.

Comment: Poder posicionarlo 100 px (por ejemplo) por debajo del elemento superior

Comment: Para eso puedes usar `margin`.

Comment: Yo pensaba que usando la propiedad positon:relative y dandole el punto exacto donde querias situarlo, los elementos restantes seguirían el flujo normal, y se situarían uno debajo del otro, pero en este caso quedarían superpuestos...

Comment: @Jogofus No, los elementos no se reajustan en la página. Siguen el flujo normal de la página en cuanto a posicionamiento se refiere. Por ejemplo, si utilizas `position: absolute` y no hay ningún `position: relative` que lo englobe entonces se saldrá del flujo normal de la página y se posicionará al principio de la página (si no lo has posicionado). Esto con `position: relative` no pasa. Si quieres más ejemplos de cómo funciona los puedes ver aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> La mejor opción para hacer lo que pretendes es usar la propiedad
>   `margin`, con eso no lo estás posicionando, simplemente estás poniendo
>   un margen en la parte superior de tu elemento, esto hará que no se
>   superposicione. Te dejo el código basándome en tu ejemeplo:

```css
.first{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:blue;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.second{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
 <section>
 <article class="first">
    <!-- Resto de estructura -->
 </article>

 <article class="second">
  <!-- Resto de estructura -->
 </article>
</section>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Entonces que ventajas presenta el position?

Comment: @Jogofus la posición está para otros casos, y tiene sus utilidades en otros casos, pero en el tuyo lo más óptimo es lo que te he dicho.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirme que casos son esos?

Comment: @Jogofus a medida que vayas programando te irás dando cuenta, pero por ejemplo en las posiciones corregidas `position: fixed` la posiciones corregidas sirven para cuando quieres que un elemento se quede fijo en la pantalla, como por ejemplo un menú de navegación.

Comment: @Jogofus no obstante hay más casos y posibilidades.

Comment: @Jogofus al fin y al cabo, ¿te sirvió mi respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Con esto serviría:

```
.first{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   background-color:blue;
   position: absolute;

}

.second{
   width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:red;
  top:100px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Yo creo que lo que se refiere es uno encima del primero separados por 100px. `first{
 background-color:blue;
  position: static;
}

.second{
 background-color:red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}`