# Centrar div siempre al centro verticalmente

Tags: css, flexbox

Buenas, estoy intentando centrar un div vertical y horizontalmente. Horizontalmente no tengo problema, uso FlexBox y siempre queda al centro, pero verticalmente ya se me complica y no lo consigo.

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: black;

}
```

Qué se me pasa ?? teniendo el direction en row el align-items: center tendría que centrarlo verticalmente en el contenedor padre, que es el body. pero no lo hace

Comment: Recuerda que body es distinto de la pantalla. Ya que el body puede ser mas alto que la pantalla y tener que utilizar el scroll para navegar en ella, o bien mas pequeña. Espero que eso aclare un poco por donde va la cosa :)

Comment: Si quieres algunas opciones sobre como posicionar horizontal y verticalmente un div en la página puedes consultar los ejemplos en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una "solución" responder si veis que es la más acertada.

Ya había probado a ponerle un height: 100% al body pero no funcionaba, así que probé a ponérselo también al html y funcionó..

Añadí a lo que ya tenía

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo siempre lo soluciono con un comportamiento en tablas..

```
<style>
    .page{
        height: 600px;
    }

    .container-1{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .container-2{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

</style>
<div class="page">
    <section class="container-1">
        <section class="container-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam quibusdam ea, neque illum quod adipisci ipsam ipsa ut magnam fuga similique cum eaque alias, culpa id sed hic, vero aut!
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente @Rodry eso lo soluciona. Lo que sucede es que tanto HTML como BODY por defecto tienen `height: auto;`, o sea, que crecen en función de su contenido.

El scroll de la ventana corresponde al elemento :root dentro del cual están aquellos dos.

Otra cosa que puedes hacer si necesitases añadir más elementos que se viesen al hacer scroll pero manteniendo tu `.container` centrado respecto de la ventana, es dejar la altura por defecto de HTML y BODY y en cualquier sección de tu página aplicar el 100% de la altura del viewport de esta manera:

```
section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```