# div sobre de otro div

Tags: css

quiero poner un div encima de otro, justo en el centro del div padre

```css
#uno {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

#padre{
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa como estaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssss
  <div id="uno">cc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Realmente estás usando al revés las posiciones. Si quieres posicionar un div sobre otro tendrías que indicar como `relative` el div padre y como `absolute` el hijo para que este tomara referencia del primero.

Posteriormente, para poder centrarlo respecto al padre podrás usar `left: 0` y `right: 0` que junto con `margin: 0 auto` harán que el `div` hijo se posicione en el centro del padre. Le tendrás que asignar una anchura ya que si no tu `div` hijo ocupará el 100% de la pantalla.

Por último, si quieres que esté el `div` hijo encima del `div` padre, puedes utilizar la propiedad `top: 0` para posicionarlo en la parte superior del `div` padre.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```css
#padre{
  position:relative;
  background-color: green;
}

#uno {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa como estaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddssss
  <div id="uno">cc</div>
</div>
```

Si tienes dudas sobre como usar la propiedad `position` puedes consultar la pregunta-respuesta que di en esta otra pregunta: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre position: relative, position: absolute y position: fixed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position).

Answer (score 5):

**Centrado absoluto usando top, left, right, bottom y margin**

```css
#padre {
  background: coral;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#uno {
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">PADRE
  <div id="uno">HIJO</div>
</div>
```

**Centrado absoluto usando left, top y transform**

```css
#uno {
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 70px;
}

#padre{
  background: coral;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">PADRE
  <div id="uno">HIJO</div>
</div>
```