# HTML, CSS, JS. Fijar encabezado

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una página web con el notepad++, la cual tiene distintas pestañas para ver una información determinada.

Entonces, lo que quiero es que, al hacer scroll, se queden dichas pestañas fijas, junto con el logo y un banner que he incluido.

Lo único que he hecho es incluir todo eso que digo (en el .HTML) en un

> div class="header"

Y luego en el .css

> position: fixed;

A ver si me podéis echar un cable con el código del .css y del .HTML

Gracias

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Comment: Pon más codigo que ese ... usa `ctrl + k` para darle formato o puedes insertarlo en un snippet de codigo (boton `<>`)  para poder probarlo. Un saludo

Comment: Has añadido eso... ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Creo que lo que estás buscando es `position: sticky`. Revisa el ejemplo que tengo en esta autopregunta-respuesta: [¿Cual es la diferencia entre position: relative, position: absolute y position: fixed?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position)

Answer (score 0):

También puedes darle estilos al cuerpo, en lugar de asignarle la posición al header. Como por ejemplo con `overflow-y:scroll`.

### [overflow-y](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

La propiedad overflow-y especifica qué hacer con los bordes superior e inferior del contenido, si se desborda el área de contenido del elemento.

---

```css
body, html
{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.header
{
    height:10%;
    background-color: #00CED1;   
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.content
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    overflow-y:scroll;        
}
```

```html
<div class="header">ENCABEZADO</div>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nisi lacus, eleifend eget tincidunt quis, viverra id erat. Suspendisse rhoncus odio eget ex commodo, eu dapibus risus malesuada. Suspendisse eget mauris sed massa fermentum pellentesque. Quisque ac nulla ligula. Sed ut tellus quis libero gravida condimentum ac non tellus. Maecenas ac feugiat nulla. Ut congue lorem sed arcu faucibus hendrerit. Nullam eget leo rutrum, aliquet lacus fermentum, tristique lacus. Nullam at hendrerit turpis, ut consequat enim. Vivamus in eros feugiat, iaculis nibh quis, pellentesque orci. Vestibulum sed mi non libero malesuada eleifend. In ullamcorper risus sed venenatis tincidunt. Pellentesque convallis lorem nec luctus ultrices. Nunc auctor lectus ut dui ultrices mattis.

Aenean tempor vestibulum nunc. Vivamus id libero in velit tincidunt tempus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse aliquet semper turpis non consequat. Ut luctus est quis imperdiet pretium. Nunc pretium nibh nec varius convallis. Cras dapibus neque felis, hendrerit luctus sapien facilisis at. Proin in placerat quam, aliquam dignissim mi. Aenean ornare augue at enim fermentum dictum. Praesent rutrum eros ac lectus finibus, quis condimentum leo commodo.

Quisque et dui in dui imperdiet rutrum. Phasellus et ante dui. Cras tempor in nunc interdum dictum. Vestibulum lacinia tempor quam. Pellentesque justo sapien, pretium ac urna id, fringilla consectetur ante. Sed in fringilla ligula. Integer arcu nibh, scelerisque sed ultricies quis, bibendum at justo. In eget est rhoncus, porta tortor a, suscipit eros. Duis luctus eros nec leo accumsan, nec cursus velit lobortis.

Donec dapibus semper justo sed rhoncus. Nulla nec ullamcorper sem. Duis dignissim vestibulum consequat. Aliquam commodo luctus ex eu venenatis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce leo dolor, hendrerit eu leo eu, dictum malesuada metus. Pellentesque non massa convallis, commodo turpis eu, eleifend massa. Integer ac cursus sapien, eu ullamcorper nulla. Cras felis quam, dignissim eget viverra vitae, suscipit sit amet neque. Vestibulum imperdiet, ex nec tempus convallis, ex lacus luctus magna, eu congue sem turpis sed est. Nulla eleifend nulla ante, ac porta ante eleifend id. Integer sit amet ligula sit amet elit ornare scelerisque vitae vitae nibh. Nunc nec sapien tortor. Quisque finibus bibendum dui vel mattis. Ut nec eros lectus. Sed pretium odio eget tellus semper, ac interdum velit eleifend.

Integer mollis vitae nisi sit amet dapibus. Proin dapibus felis eu convallis scelerisque. In a justo ac mauris sollicitudin cursus sed eget magna. Donec nec eros sit amet orci mollis blandit. Nam eu malesuada ante. Nam non rutrum orci, id placerat mauris. Maecenas sem felis, ornare eget ante quis, vehicula mollis lorem. Vivamus porta urna ut maximus sollicitudin. Cras iaculis suscipit tellus, eget maximus urna accumsan in. Fusce nec turpis a lectus tristique convallis. Sed vel ipsum gravida mi blandit molestie nec accumsan mauris. Aliquam sit amet libero sed mauris volutpat maximus quis ut enim. Sed consequat porttitor lobortis. Duis ornare ullamcorper euismod. Nulla facilisi.

Sed magna est, pretium eget tristique ac, dictum vitae erat. Donec aliquet vel libero vel ornare. Nulla iaculis sagittis purus id commodo. Nam cursus mi id leo rutrum, sed fermentum nibh interdum. Donec commodo ipsum a est luctus, sit amet dictum urna lobortis. Aenean porttitor lectus a erat pulvinar convallis. Sed scelerisque ex ut risus dignissim, nec ultrices nunc tincidunt. Sed dignissim vulputate erat cursus finibus. Maecenas condimentum interdum diam eu maximus. Ut sit amet bibendum dolor. Aliquam vitae nunc ac purus volutpat tempor. Vestibulum sit amet urna ut nibh consectetur imperdiet. Nam interdum, odio blandit mollis scelerisque, mauris dolor imperdiet turpis, sit amet laoreet diam enim vel nisl. Duis quis vehicula ante. Pellentesque vulputate ornare dui ac consectetur. Nullam vel enim urna.

Proin eu pretium justo, vitae finibus arcu. Cras nec posuere nulla, et elementum nisl. Praesent a magna a est dictum maximus. Sed eget leo neque. Integer aliquet neque a odio placerat ullamcorper. Integer quis justo eleifend est laoreet dapibus. Etiam aliquam lorem sit amet odio ullamcorper, quis feugiat dolor lobortis.

Suspendisse eget odio tincidunt, vulputate ante non, pulvinar quam. Nam tellus est, pellentesque quis iaculis et, tempus sit amet est. Duis aliquam suscipit neque, non condimentum nibh vestibulum sit amet. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce molestie orci ac lectus lobortis, eu efficitur tellus volutpat. Integer in lacus blandit, malesuada nulla non, laoreet lacus. Cras aliquam, dui auctor interdum tempus, erat dolor fringilla massa, vitae aliquet ante libero vel nunc. In pellentesque massa vitae condimentum aliquet. Nulla sollicitudin est ut justo faucibus, in blandit ex finibus.

Duis porttitor est est, et suscipit mi molestie in. Phasellus congue suscipit finibus. Vivamus aliquet ante nunc, et tempor est vestibulum nec. Aenean in viverra sapien. Vestibulum bibendum pharetra risus eu eleifend. Pellentesque nec rhoncus mauris, quis mollis quam. Donec et tortor semper urna ornare mattis vitae in magna. Cras consectetur libero libero, vitae scelerisque libero iaculis vel.

Nam pellentesque, metus et malesuada tempus, magna justo eleifend dui, eu aliquam nisl ante ac mauris. Donec tellus augue, rutrum nec pulvinar vel, consectetur quis odio. Nam tincidunt ultricies lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In aliquet mauris consectetur sapien commodo rhoncus. Nulla augue nisi, eleifend in risus id, interdum rhoncus orci. Nunc auctor enim justo, ac placerat libero fermentum ut. Sed dictum nisi quam, et pretium ex fringilla quis.</div>
```