# Cómo hacer hover a una clase desde un botón

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema y no sé si existe la solución.

tengo una imagen oculta que se activa al hacer :hover pero ese es el problema, que necesito hacer hover encima de ella para que que se active y pues ocupe toda la pantalla. pero no puedo dejar un poco de la imagen descubierta porque se veria muy feo. quiero que esa imagen se active haciendo hover en encima de otro objeto como un botón o otra imagen.

ya he intentado de todo los modos, poniendo botones con la misma clase de la imagen pero no me funciona.

```
<img class="image" src="https://msaf.com.fj/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/500x500.png"/> 

<style>
.image {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
.image:hover{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
 </style>
```

Comment: esta solución te puede servir: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156794/hacer-hover-en-un-div-y-se-aplique-hover-en-un-div-hermano. por otra parte llevas unas cuantas preguntas y no has aceptado nunca una respuesta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
img {
   display: none;
}

button:hover + img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Muestra imagen</button>
<img src="https://t1.uc.ltmcdn.com/images/6/1/6/img_por_que_mi_gato_maulla_mucho_26616_600.jpg">
```

Mediante **CSS** se puede hacer que al hacer `hover` a un elemento las reglas **CSS** de otro cambien. Para que esto sea posible la relación entre elementos debe ser muy específica, en el caso de hermanos es posible. Lo que hace el selector que he usado es que detecta cuando el ratón está por encima del botón y entonces busca una imagen adyacente a él y la pone en visible.