# ¿Como puedo hacer para que mi flex-container no afecte a un item-flex posicionado de forma absoluta?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background: pink;">

            <a style="position: relative">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
                <p>Username</p>
                <ul style="position: absolute">
                    <li>
                        item item item item item item
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

¿No se supone que el `<ul>` esta afuera del flujo y no tiene dimensiones definidas, debería ajustarse según su contenido es decir, seguirse estirando sin generar saltos de linea pero no lo hace y actúa como si tuviese un ancho definido?

¿Podrían explicarme esto?

¿Como puedo hacer para mandar mi enlace con `position: relative` al final del contenedor y que a su vez la alineación no afecte a la lista? es decir aunque el contenedor flex sea justify-content: flex-end; la lista igual se estire sin generar saltos de linea a causa de su contenido?

Esto ocurre por el `display: flex` que tiene la clase `row` pero si la quito, todo marcha bien. pero no se como alinear mi enlace junto con la lista posicionada de forma absoluta al final del contenedor.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo, el resultado que estas esperando es exactamente lo que te sale, pero queres que las palaras ITEM esten todas en la misma linea?

Answer (score 1):

Te pasa eso porque la propiedad `display : absolute` se posiciona en relacion al primer padre que tenga la propiedad `display` distinta de `initial` o `static`. Si no hubiera ningun elemento con dichas clases, se posicionará respecto del `html`.

En este caso, el padre va a ser tu elemento `a`, (ya que tiene la propiedad `display : relative`), que tiene ese ancho que te provoca la duda.
Lo solucionas agregando `width: 100%` a este elemento `a`.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background: pink;">

            <a style="position: relative; width:100%">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
                <p>Username</p>
                <ul style="position: absolute">
                    <li>
                        item item item item item item
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta muy completa donde explica detalladamente el funcionamiento de la propiedad **display** https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position