# ¿Cómo puedo centrar una línea de texto encima de una imagen?

Tags: html, css

Tengo unas imágenes en un slider con texto pero no consigo centrarlo. Me quedan de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de las imágenes es este:

```
<div class="mySlides">
    <div class="container">
      <a title="Dobles Títulos Internacionales" href="http://www.etsit.upm.es/internacional/dobles-titulos-internacionales.html">
        <img src="https://www.bennett.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/engineering-1024x371.jpg" width="900px" height="150">
      </a>
      <div class="centered"><b>DOBLES TÍTULOS INTERNACIONALES</b></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Y por otro lado el código css de centered es:

```
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fc8e04;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;  
}
```

También he probado con justify-content: center; y no lo he conseguidi. ¿Alguien sabría decirme cómo puedo conseguir que ese texto aparezca centrado encima de la imagen?

---

Al probar las líneas de código dadas por @carlos-duarte me sale el texto de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @BetaM tan solo horizontal, quiero que esté en la parte inferior de la imagen pero centrado

Answer (score 2):

Cambiar el posicionamiento del `div` que contiene al texto parece ser la opción mas simple.

Basándonos en la doc. [de Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/position) lo que haremos será cambiar su naturaleza de `position: static;` a un posicionamiento *relativo*.

Para no duplicar información, [te recomiendo leas esta publicación de la misma comunidad (*y que no es mia*) donde se explica el tema de posicionamiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position)

```html
    <style>
      .centered {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="container">
          <a title="Dobles Títulos Internacionales" href="http://www.etsit.upm.es/internacional/dobles-titulos-internacionales.html">
            <img src="https://www.bennett.edu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/engineering-1024x371.jpg" width="900px" height="150">
          </a>
          <div class="centered"><b>DOBLES TÍTULOS INTERNACIONALES</b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En este punto lo único que debes hacer para mover a voluntad el texto es aplicar alguna medida a:

- top
- bottom
- left
- right

Answer (score 2):

Prueba establecer el contenedor en position relative

```
.mySlides{
position: relative;
}
```

y el texto con la clase

```
.centered{
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
}
```

intentalo y trata de alinear el texto a ver si te funciona correctamente.