# Como puedo dejar el menu fijo cuando haga scroll?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Buenas estoy montando una pagina web con Bootstrap me gustaría saber si hay alguna clase especifica o como podría hacer para dejar mi menu estatico al hacer scroll hacia abajo. He estado mirando guias y no me ha dejado ponerlo a puro html, me pregunto si hay algun tipo de problema de querer modificar clases de bootstrap a puro codigo html.

````
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <span class="text-primary fs-22 fw-bold">Menu</span>
            </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Inicio
                </a>
              </li>

              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Equipo</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
              </li>
              </ul>

            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" aria-label="email">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-primary-outline-success" type="button">Suscribete</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>```
````

Comment: Hola, bootstrap tiene una clase fixed-top puedes checar un ejemplo aca https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbar-fixed/

Comment: Pon el inicio de tu <nav> en el ejemplo que has puesto, te lo has dejado y no se ve tu menu.  Y normalmente las clases container y container-fluid envuelven todo lo que va dentro del body, nav incluido. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta

Comment: Dejo por aquí un enlace a otra pregunta por si esa solución [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385432/251176) te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

A la etiqueta que contenga todos los componentes de tu menú agrégale en su estilo posición fija y acomódalo en la pantalla con top/bottom y left/right; e.g. :

```
<div style="position: fixed; right: 10vw; bottom: 10vw;">
<h3>Ejemplo de menú flotante</h3>
<a>cta</a>
</div>
```