# Las posiciones de unos divs generan un comportamiento no adecuado

Tags: javascript, css, html5, responsive

Tengo esta porción de código que he hecho y la verdad la veo bien, pero tengo unos problemitas. Los Cards no se ponen detrás del navbar cuando esta queda fija y tampoco detrás de menú.

He aislado el problema y se da por las posiciones de las cards, he comentado algo sobre las lineas del CSS para que vean donde esta el problema.

```js
let nav = document.querySelector("nav");

window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=> {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20){
            nav.classList.add("sticky");
    }else{
        nav.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
})

const body = document.querySelector("body"),
    openMenu = document.querySelector(".openMenu"),
    closeMenu = document.querySelector("closeMenu");


openMenu.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    nav.classList.add("active");
});

body.addEventListener("click", e =>{
    let clicked = e.target;
    if (!clicked.classList.contains("openMenu") && !clicked.classList.contains("menu")) {
        nav.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
```

```css
/* ===== Google Font Import - Poppins ===== */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600&display=swap");

:root {
  /* ===== Colors ===== */
  --primary-color: #0177DE;
  --secondary-color: #045dac;
  --text-dark-color: #333;

  /* ====== Transition ====== */
  --tran-05: all 0.5s ease;
  --tran-03: all 0.3s ease;
  --tran-02: all 0.2s ease;
}

/* Tablets */
@media (max-width: 1245px){
    .profile-card{
        width: calc(50% - 10px);
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    nav .nav-content .openMenu{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .menu{
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        left: -100%;
        top: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #191919;
        z-index: 100;
        transition: var(--tran-05);
    }
    nav.active .menu{
        left: 0%;
    }
    nav.active .nav-content .logo a{
        font-size: 1.5rem !important;
        color: white;
    }
    nav.active .nav-content .navLogo{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: var(--tran-03);
    }
    .logo-toggle .logo{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex !important;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .nav-content .logo a{
        font-size: 1.5rem !important;
    }
    .logo-toggle .closeMenu{
        color: white;
        font-size: 1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-content .nav-links{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .nav-links li a{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: white !important;
    }
    .nav-links li a::before{
        background-color: white !important;
    }
    .container{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .profile-card{
        max-width: 90% !important;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
/* Movil */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    nav .nav-content .openMenu{
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
    .menu{
        width: 60%;
    }
    nav.active .menu{
        left: 0%;
    }
    nav.active .nav-content .logo a{
        font-size: 1.1rem !important;
    }
    nav.active .nav-content .navLogo{
        opacity: 0;
        transition: var(--tran-03);
    }
    .logo-toggle .logo{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex !important;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .logo-toggle .closeMenu{
        color: white;
        font-size: 1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-content .nav-links{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .nav-links li a{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .container{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .profile-card{
        max-width: 90% !important;
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
}
/********** Navbar **********/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}
nav.sticky{
    padding: 15px 20px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
nav .nav-content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
nav .nav-content .openMenu{
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
.nav-content .logo a{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
.logo-toggle .logo{
        display: none;
    }
nav.sticky .nav-content .openMenu{
    color: white;
}
nav.sticky .nav-content .logo a{
    color: white;
}
.nav-content .nav-links{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-content .nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 8px;
}
.nav-links li a{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: var(--text-dark-color);
    padding: 10px 4px;
    transition: var(--tran-04);
}
.nav-links li a::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--text-dark-color);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}
.nav-links li:hover a::before{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
.nav-links li a:hover{
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
nav.sticky .nav-links li a{
    color: white;
}
nav.sticky .nav-links li:hover a::before{
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: var(--text-dark-color);
}
nav.sticky .nav-links li a:hover{
    color: var(--text-dark-color);
}
/********** Cards **********/
.container{
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.profile-card{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 370px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 24px;
    padding: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    /* Sin relative, no aparece */
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.profile-card::before{
    content: '';
    /* Sin absolute, no aparece */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 36%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 24px 24px 0 0;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}
.image{
    /* Sin relative, se queda atras */
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.image .profile-img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
}
.profile-card .text-data {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--text-dark-color);
}
.text-data .name{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.text-data .job{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.profile-card .media-buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.media-buttons .links{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 8px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}
.profile-card .buttons{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.buttons .button{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 8px 24px;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
}
.buttons .button:hover{
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}
.profile-card .analytics{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.analytics .data{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: var(--text-dark-color);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-right: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.data i{
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}
.data:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8db5c68b69.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-content">
        <div class="logo navLogo">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars openMenu"></i>
            <a href="/">Users</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="logo-toggle">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="/">Users</a>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark closeMenu"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Others</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="profile-card">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633332755192-727a05c4013d" alt="imgProfile" class="profile-img">
        </div>

        <div class="text-data">
            <span class="name">User Name</span>
            <span class="job">Title or Job's User</span>
        </div>

        <div class="media-buttons">
            <a href="#" style="background: #4267b2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #e1306c;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #d71e18;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #1da1f2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #000;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #25d366;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #0e76a8;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #6699ff;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button">
                Subscribe
            </button>
            <button class="button">
                Message
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="analytics">
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    25k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    63k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="uil uil-share"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    81k
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-card">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.growcropsonline.com/assets/img/agent-2.jpg" alt="imgProfile" class="profile-img">
        </div>

        <div class="text-data">
            <span class="name">User Name</span>
            <span class="job">Title or Job's User</span>
        </div>

        <div class="media-buttons">
            <a href="#" style="background: #4267b2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #e1306c;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #d71e18;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #1da1f2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #000;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button">
                Subscribe
            </button>
            <button class="button">
                Message
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="analytics">
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    25k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    63k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="uil uil-share"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    81k
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-card">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/app-assets/images/user/12.jpg" alt="imgProfile" class="profile-img">
        </div>

        <div class="text-data">
            <span class="name">User Name</span>
            <span class="job">Title or Job's User</span>
        </div>

        <div class="media-buttons">
            <a href="#" style="background: #4267b2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #e1306c;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #d71e18;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #1da1f2;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" style="background: #000;" class="links">
                <i class="fa-brands fa-tiktok"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <button class="button">
                Subscribe
            </button>
            <button class="button">
                Message
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="analytics">
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    25k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    63k
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="data">
                <i class="uil uil-share"></i>
                <span class="number">
                    81k
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

He leido [este post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37930/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-position-relative-position-absolute-y-position) y aunque su aporte es enorme, no logro entender porque se comporta así, he hecho cambios y he buscado de muchas maneras pero ya no puedo seguir, y por eso vengo.

Tambien tengo un pequeño "algo" que no me gusta, cuando cierro el menu, cambia las letras al color azul que tiene normalmente, he manipulado esas clases y la verdad es que no logro quitar ese pequeño error.

PD: los `<br>` son solo para tema de altura.

---

Puedo incluir en la pregunta las siguientes dudas?

- El orden de las media querys (MQ) es el correcto?? CSS es secuencial, siempre he colocado las MQ al inicio, primero las grandes y luego las chicas (moviles) pero al ser secuencial, no se si las MQ deberian ir al final de todo.
- En las MQ, he usado mucho el `! important`, eso es válido?? es que sin eso no acepta los estilos y queria saber si el abuso de eso no se veria como mala practica.

PD2: Solo la respuesta de la posicion de los cards sera tomada en cuenta para ser aceptada, las otras son uun extra, las pueden responder pero para conocimiento general.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste darle z-index a tu `nav`?

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: var(--tran-03);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: :-( no la verdad pensé que todo estaba en el `position` e ignoré por completo el `z-index` y en efecto eso resolvió todo, odio este tipo de errores tan bobos. Aceptaré tu respuesta y si alguien quiere responder las otras dudas estaré feliz de ver que me dicen. Gracias. [Más sobre z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)